# Google Direction API : MRT/LRT data inconsistency

Tags: google-directory-api

When we are calling direction API and routing response for "Transit_mode = rail" is very unstable.

Can you please advise the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Your question is uncomplete and not very clear.
Post your code, explain what you mean with "unstable" response, we don't work for google and we can't find the problem for you. If you have a problem post it and explain it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.